# Emails sent through our application are going to spam or not comming at all

Tags: email, spam

When sending emails through our rails app they are going to spam in some email accounts(hotmail) and not coming at all in others.

We are using sendmail to send the emails. The sender email id is `no-reply@xyz.com`. What could be the possible reasons for this. Where do we check the logs for the sendmail(ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

- Check your MX and PTR records
- Use static IP
- Check [blacklist](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)
- See raw message/headers in hotmail

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [alvosu](https://serverfault.com/users/68346/alvosu)s suggestions I would add

- [SPF Records](http://www.openspf.org/) to your Domain for outgoing email
- [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM) DomainKeys Identified Mail